# Como hacer nombres random

Tags: php, array, variables, random

quiero hacer que en un texto que escriban por una web php, tenga un nombre random, el tema es que el que tengo creado crea el mismo nombre en todos los textos, y quiero que sea random, no se si me explico.
Tengo esto:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$charactersLength = strlen($characters);
$randomString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
}
return $randomString;
}

echo generateRandomString();
```

Y quiero que el generateRamdomString(); esté adentro de esto:

```
echo "<tr><td> $mensaje</td></tr>";
```

Sería adelante de " $mensaje"

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78405/discussion-on-question-by-matiphp-como-hacer-nombres-random).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya se ha dicho en comentarios, puedes usar la siguiente función, (propuesta originalmente [en esta respuesta de SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4356295/5587982)) para generar una cadena random de 10 caracteres:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
return $randomString;
}
```

Si quieres más o menos caracteres le puedes pasar la cantidad que quieras al llamar la función.

---

Para tus otras dudas, yo recomendaría que uses una cadena a la cual le agregues los datos y luego la imprimes al final.

Por ejemplo:

```
$mensaje=": es el random generado"; 
$strHTML="<tr><td><b>".generateRandomString()."</b>$mensaje</td></tr>"; 
echo $strHTML;
```

Esta forma es particularmente útil sobre todo cuando:

- en el código hay partes HTML / PHP... en esos casos muchos programadores escriben código mezclado en el que se va pasando de PHP a HTML y viceversa, lo cual es lícito, pero resulta en un código que hace daño a la vista y muy difícil de analizar, depurar, mantener.
- en el código hay contenido que se irá construyendo en partes diferentes, como en condiciones `if`, bulces `for`  o `while`, etc. En esos casos podrías *abrir*  tu variable `$strHTML` al inicio del código e ir concatenando contenido durante todo el recorrido del código para imprimirla al final.